# how to change decimal places in matplotlib ax.text in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data set call 'df' and trying to use one of column data as a axis of graph.

The data appear on a graph as 11.58 so I would like to change it to one decimal place which is 11.5

Here is the code I've got.

```
if df['gear'] is no None:
    ax2.text[10,5, df['gear'][0], size=5, weight='bold', color='black', rotation=0., ha="center", va="center")
```

To change it to one decimal place, I've tried it as below but it won't work

```
if df['gear'] is no None:
        ax2.text[10,5, df['gear'][0], "{:.1f}", size=5, weight='bold', color='black', rotation=0., ha="center", va="center")
```

can someone please tell me how to change decimal point in ax.text.
Thanks

Comment: `ax2.text[10, 5, f"{df['gear'][0]:.1f}", ...)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `round` function to round off the value to one decimal position

```
round(number, number of digits)
```

```
ax2.text[10,5, round(df['gear'][0], 1), size=5, weight='bold', color='black', rotation=0., ha="center", va="center")
```